# Capturing blocks with multiple allowed types/signatures

Tags: crystal-lang

Is it possible to capture a block inside a method that has multiple allowed signatures?

```
alias IoBlockFormatter = Severity, Time, String, String, IO -> Nil
alias StringBlockFormatter = Severity, Time, String, String -> String

class Formatter
  def initialize(@io : IO, &@block : IoBlockFormatter | StringBlockFormatter)
  end
end
```

In this example, I'm defining two different function types, and I want to allow the block that my `Formatter` class can accept to be either type. My first attempt at this tries to use the union of the two types, but the compiler complains about expecting a Function type, not a union of two Proc types.

```
expected block type to be a function type, not (Proc(Severity, Time, String, String, IO, Nil) | Proc(Severity, Time, String, String, String))

  def initialize(@io : IO, &@block : IoBlockFormatter | StringBlockFormatter)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have one method take multiple block types, as the block is typed from the method signature, not the other way around. Once the correct method is found, the types of the block arguments are deduced from `yield` with non-captured blocks, and from the type of `&block` in captured arguments. You also cannot have two overloads with the same arguments and a block, even if the block is used differently for similar reasons.

Comment: What's the reason that a block's type signature isn't taken into account when defining a method? Naively it seems to me like it's a part of the type signature of the function, just like other arguments.

Comment: Because when you pass a block, you don't give the type of the arguments, you just use `|a, b, c|`. This means that to work out which overload to call, you need to know the type of a, b, and c, but to type them you need to know which method you're calling. This is a recursive lookup and therefore impossible.